# Stock data carry over to next day

Tags: php, mysql, stock

I have stock table like below:

```
date         item   new stock    sale  total
1-1-2000     abc      3          2     1
1-1-2000     bcd      4          2     2
1-1-2000     ffs      9          1     8
```

I need to that 'total value should be carry over next day for each products. how do I do that in mySQL. The data carry over process is on each day. If I add entry on next day, it should calculate last day value of 'total'.

Comment: if it's a calculated value, i shouldnt be in the database, in the general case. however i think a trigger should do the work

Comment: ok so on 1-2-2000 you get three new rows, and new stock and sale go to 0 and total gets carried over, right? never design a database this way

Comment: but if you have to, each day have your app do an insert into that table the current date,item,0,0,total with an insert and select stmt for values get all rows from today-1

Comment: Please suggest me a good design table so that product carry data to next day in PHP and MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE items (
itemid int not null AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
itemname varchar(40) not null,
onhand int not null, # current inv based on sales and inv adjustments
price decimal (10,2) not null   # default price per item
) engine=innodb;

CREATE TABLE sale (
saleid int not null AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, # basically an invoice #
customerid int not null,    # joined to a customer table
saledate timestamp not null
) engine=innodb;

CREATE TABLE sale_detail (
saleid int not null,        # invoice #
lineid int not null,        # lines 1 and up for this invoice
itemid int not null,        # item sold
qty int not null,           # quantity sold
price decimal (10,2) not null   # price per item can be overriden from items table value
) engine=innodb;

CREATE TABLE inventory_adj (
adjid int not null AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
itemid int not null,
trans_typ int not null,     # 0=purchase stock, 1=inventory adj, 2=shrinkage, 3=return, etc
adjdate timestamp not null, # now()
qty int not null            # amt of change, positive is acquisition, negative is depletion
) engine=innodb;
```

prime your items table with onhand amount. this is your inventory level. goes down from sales, goes up with purchases into the inventory_adj table, gets adj there too when you take inventory, etc. this is a normalized data model. True, the onhand in items does not technically need to be kept, it can be calculated on the fly but that is a little slow. As long as you create transactions and update onhand based on sales etc and commit the transaction you are safe. Plus this gives you a better audit on what happened to get you there. Of course add other columns like the name of the user making the entries in sales and inventory adj.

Comment: Ya. but i need to carrry over data to next day. if entry today xxx item and dat value should be carry same xxx item to next day. How can i do dat in PHP and MySQL.

Comment: @ganeshjogii the inventory is maintained is my response confusing? i can explain more. you do not need to carry forward to a new row everyday

Comment: @ganeshjogii do you need some examples of how the above would be implemented?

Comment: Ha please give me some example. So that I can get understand.

Comment: you would insert a row into items with it correct inventory level. note that you have only 1 row in items at any time for a given item. prob not a bad idea to have a matching insert put into inventory_adj with a trans_typ of perhaps 1 meaning you took inventory. so for now on you just do updates on items since that item is in there already. so if you sell an 6 qty of an item, your wrap in a transaction the update against items (subtracting 6 from onhand) plus the insert to sales and sale_detail. then commit the transaction

Comment: let's say you purchase to increase inventory for item X qty 100. you begin a transaction, update items for X by adding 100 to onhand. you insert a row into inventory_adj with trans_typ=0 and qty=100. and commit the transaction.

Comment: when you want to find out how many items you have of item X just go to the 1 row in items that tells you your onhand amt. dates have nothing to do with it and just over complicate the problem. the other tables give you an audit. the items.onhand should equal the sum of the qty in inventory_adj (they are positive and neg #'s) minus the sum of qty in sale_detail for that given itemid.

Comment: Thanks a lot Drew. It really helps me lot.